# How to add a blank field in a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that works and populates well. All I want to know is how to add a blank field. This way if the user inadvertently selects something they can select the blank row rather than pressing Ctrl-0.

In my code I tried adding Items.Add(DBNull.Value) but to no avail, as shown in my code. All it does is give me an error which is why it is rem'd out.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub FillCombobox(strHeaderText As String, strPropertyName As String, strTableName As String)
    Using cboBox As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        With cboBox
            .HeaderText = strHeaderText
            .DataPropertyName = strPropertyName
            .DataSource = GetData("Select * From " & strTableName)
            .ValueMember = .DataPropertyName
           '.Items.Add(DBNull.Value)
        End With

        dgrMain.Columns.Add(cboBox)
    End Using
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```
Private Function GetData(ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DataTable
    Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCommand, strConn)
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(strConn)
    con.Open()
    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, con)
    da.SelectCommand = command
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    con.Close()
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: You have to add it (or insert it) into your DataSource.

Comment: As @LarsTech noted, you can't just add a row to the control if it's bound to a DataSource. I would create a local DataTable and fill it with the data from `strTableName` then add the blank row.

Comment: I follow what you are both are saying. I am able to add a blank column, but my struggle is adding a blank row.

Comment: Something like `Dim dt As DataTable = GetData("...")`  `dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.NewRow, 0)`  `.DataSource = dt`

Comment: Are you **REALLY** using `SELECT *` for your ComboBox data source?

Comment: LarsTech it works but it gives me an error when loading.  Here is my getdata:

Comment: Private Function GetData(ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DataTable
        Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCommand, strConn)
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(strConn)

        con.Open()
        Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, con)
    da.SelectCommand = command

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        con.Close()

        Return dt
    End Function

Comment: What is the value of strTableName?

Comment: This is the table I am querying from that populates the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. The table is called Filetype.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Do you know how to paste in a screenshot?

Comment: Just edit your question with the text copy of the exception.